# Error while running jar from .bat file

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jar, unsupported-class-version

I'm getting `UnSupportedClassVersionNumber` exception while calling `jar` from `.bat file`.

```
set LIBRARY_PATH=D:\endecabatch\JAR

echo %LIBRARY_PATH%

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14 

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\lib

set CLASSPATH=%PATH%

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%LIBRARY_PATH%\sqljdbc.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%LIBRARY_PATH%\log4j-1.2.16.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%LIBRARY_PATH%\auditlog_1.0.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%LIBRARY_PATH%\jdbc_1.0.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%LIBRARY_PATH%\EndecaBatch.jar

java -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.heb.endeca.batch.BatchManager "D:\endecabatch\" "properties\LOCAL\" "FULL" "ALL"
```

From eclipse i've exported the jar. I've changed the `jre to 1.5.0_14` and compiler version to `1.5` and then exported the `jar`. Still it is showing the same error. Please help.

This is the `Exception` i'm getting

```
D:\endecabatch>echo D:\endecabatch\JAR
D:\endecabatch\JAR

D:\endecabatch>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14

D:\endecabatch>set PATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib

D:\endecabatch>set CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib

D:\endecabatch>set CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;D:\endecabatch\JAR\sqljdbc.jar

D:\endecabatch>set CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;D:\endecabatch\JAR\sqljdbc.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\log4j-1.2.16.jar

D:\endecabatch>set CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;D:\endecabatch\JAR\sqljdbc.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\auditlog_1.0.jar

D:\endecabatch>set CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;D:\endecabatch\JAR\sqljdbc.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\auditlog_1.0.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\jdbc_1.0.jar

D:\endecabatch>set CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;D:\endecabatch\JAR\sqljdbc.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\auditlog_1.0.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\jdbc_1.0.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\EndecaBatch.jar

D:\endecabatch>java -classpath C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;D:\endecabatch\JAR\sqljdbc.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\auditlog_1.0.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\jdbc_1.0.jar;D:\endecabatch\JAR\EndecaBatch.jar com.heb.endeca.batch.BatchManager "D:\endecabatch\" "properties\LOCAL\" "FULL" "ALL"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

Comment: What's the version of Java on the target system?  You might also want to post the entire messsage ;)

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace to check where the error could be.

Comment: classpath should just be paths, no? Not pointing at specific .jar files, just the directory those jars are in...

Comment: @MarcB: It can also include jars http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Comment: I've added complete stacktrace.

Comment: We would like to know Which version of JDK are in use?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did a mistake while generating jar. I've changed compiler version in `windows-> Preferences` instead of change it in `buildPath -> ConfigureBuildPath -> compiler`

Now i can run my java application from batch file correctly.